# Is it possible to use data from one table to search and retrieve records in another table in MS Access?

Tags: database, ms-access

Newbies with programing and only has limited (beginner) knowledge with Python.

I am trying to build a database for historical prices on Equipment. Here is my thought process:

- Table 1: Contains specifications of the equipment, including Tags (unique ID to identify the item / record, will also be used as Primary Key of table 1), Item descriptions, Model #'s, etc.
- Table 2: Using Tags as the identifier (also primary key of table 2), each item will have multiple records which contain Purchase Order #, Unit Price, Currency and etc.
  Objective: To create a search form which I can use any parameters from Table 1 to locate a tag (an item), and this tag can then be used to locate records associate with it in Table 2.

I'm not sure if I have stated my intention clearly.. I only have basic knowledge with Access and how to create search form. My question is if this objective is possible. If so, what do I need to do or how do I program it?

Thank you so much!

I have created Table 1 and 2 with necessary columns. I tried linking tables and it just gets super complicated for me...

Comment: Use an unbound combobox listing tags for selection of tag as filter criteria. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html. When you have code with issue, post question. Alternatively, use intrinsic filter/search tools on ribbon. Depends how 'user-friendly' you want to make.